# Is there any benchmarking tool for parachain collator node performance?

Tags: benchmarking, parachain-collator, performance

Like there is e.g. `polkadot benchmark machine --chain kusama --verify-duration 60` for the relaychain, is there something similar for the parachains? If not maybe some custom tool for measuring parachain node performance? Or how would you test this?

Answer (score 0):

The node provided by [substrate-parachain-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template) provides the same command:

```
./parachain-collator benchmark machine
2022-07-19 17:55:28 Running machine benchmarks...
```

Comment: but I tried several parachains (Shiden, Zeitgeist, Robonomics, Polkadex, Moonriver) and it did not work for them except Moonriver. with all the others I'm getting this error:
```error: Found argument 'machine' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
    polkadot benchmark <SUBCOMMAND>```

Comment: Then they are not using a recent Substrate version or they do not expose that command. This is not a Substrate but a parachain problem.